# Изображения в Android

Tags: android

Кто поможет, есть проблема при отображении изображений, на телефонах с разрешением до full HD они все примерно одного размера, а вот на телефонах выше full HD ничего не разглядеть, описание становится очень мелким. Как сделать, чтобы на всех телефонах изображения были одинаковые? Грузить для каждого разрешения свой размер не вариант - их там тысячи.

Comment: Для хорошего растягивания картинок есть технология 9-patch. О ней можно почитать в статье на хабре: https://habrahabr.ru/post/113623/ Если вам это не подходит, то можно сделать несколько версий картинок с разным разрешением. А по поводу размера текста: если текст не в картинке, а отображается через TextView, то можно указать разные размеры для разных экранов. По ссылке гайд от Гугла о поддержке разных экранов: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Задайте `ImageView` конкретные размеры в `dp` и будут они одинаковыми. Либо вставляйте картинки из кода, "подгоняя" под нужные размеры. Есть также небезисвестные библиотеки, облегчающие работу с картинками.

Comment: как именно вы показываете свои изображения? приложите к вопросу разметку, что хотите получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте еще 2 `layout` тем же именем, только для других разрешений

- **Это ваша разметка** - `res/layout/main_activity.xml`
- **Для таблеток с размером `600dp` и выше** - `res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml`
- **И для `720 dp` и выше** - `res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml`

Получится, зададите в каждом `layout` для `ImageView` разные размеры